# Calculating NPath Complexity

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to calculate the NPath Complexity within a function, but I'm unsure what parts I count.

My understanding is that it'll sum:

- If
- Else
- Else If
- Switch
- Case
- Default
- Do
- While

Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to include operators such as `&&` `||` and `? :`, since these themselves can produce alternate execution paths.

Comment: You also left `for` out of your list of control-flow statements ...

Comment: actually take a look here http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/principles_and_practices/complexity/complexity-java-method.html the term is "cyclomatic complexity", there's actually a few other things I forgot, such as `try/catch/finally`...

Comment: npath and cyclomatic are different types of complexity and are measured differently.

Comment: Okay, I looked this up. Seems N-path takes into account the possible outcome of all operations, but OP only mentions flow-control. Do you think he meant CC?

Comment: Its possible... though it probably needs more clarification to determine exactly what the OP is after.

Comment: I just want to know what's included in NPath Complexity :)

Comment: well, I think the short answer is *everything*, but I think it comes down to the number of possible outcomes for a function. This article gives a basic summary: http://codingswag.ghost.io/cyclomatic-and-npath-complexity-explained/

Answer (score 1):

The NPath Complexity is the sum of the possible routes through your code (ignoring cycles).

The complexity therefore depends on the structure of your code rather than just the tokens:

```
if (x) {
   if (y) {
     // Do something
   } else {
    // Do something else
   }
} else {
  // Do something even more else
}
```

Has 3 possible paths that could be taken, depending on the values of x and y.

As you nest control structures more deeply, the number of possible paths increases exponentially.

Skimming this code: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/rules/design/NpathComplexity.html
will give an idea of the complexity of calculating the complexity:-)